# Get youtube video's comments - dart

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, dart

I'am trying to get youtube video's comments from my dart console application. I create application in google console.

Then I try to get video list:

```dart
import "package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart" as youtube;
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

void main() {

  http.Client client = new http.Client();  
  youtube.YoutubeApi api = new youtube.YoutubeApi(client);


  api.videos.list("title", id: "ZkGSR0Q492g").then((youtube.VideoListResponse list) {

  //    print("List length: " + list.items.length);

  });

}
```

When I run this file in console - I get error:

`Uncaught Error: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)`

I understand that I never indicated API-key applications. I think that the error due to this.

But I can not figure out where I need to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use package "googleapis_oauth". And in this package we have method `clientViaApiKey` in `auth_io.dart`. This is solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to create an authenticated client using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_oauth2_client (detailed instructions in the README.md)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use it. But, if I understand correctly, this method involves the use of client authentication? In my case, I need to use a public Youtube API.

Comment: The message indicates that you need a API project and pass the project ID with the requests so the YouTube API can count your requests against the free quota.

Comment: now I use package "googleapis_oauth". And in this package we have method `clientViaApiKey` in `auth_io.dart`. This is solve my problem. Thank you very much for help!